# j_spring_security_logout with extjs4

Tags: spring-security, extjs4

i'm using spring security
and i have a login form  to connect i use this and it work

```
connect:function(button, event, opt) 
   {
       var form = button.up('form');
       form.getForm().submit({
           url:'j_spring_security_check',
            method:'POST', 

            success:function(){
                //Ext.Msg.alert('Login OK', 'success');
                //this.getLogin().close();
                   Ext.getCmp('log').close();
                   var view1 = Ext.widget('home');

        }
```

and i have button logout  but idont know haw to use url:'j_spring_security_logout'

any one have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the logout-url in the logout filter:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-logout

```
<http ...>
...
    <logout logout-url="/your-logout-page" logout-success-url="/"/>
</http>
```

Access to it from PHP. You need to define `url` according to the configuration above:

```
...
form.getForm().submit({
           url:'your-logout-page',
...
```

Also, You can put the link like

```
<a href="\j_spring_security_logout"/>" > Logout</a>
```

Comment: i havee not a form to submit 

and for url it should be 

url:'j_spring_security_logout'

Comment: The `j_spring_security_logout` is the default URL and I show above how to change it. Do you have a question how to call to the URL from extjs4? 
You can put the link like  `<a href="\j_spring_security_logout"/>" > Logout</a>`

Comment: Once again: do you have a question how to call to the URL from extjs4?